# libvlc_media_new_path not working

Tags: c++, qt, libvlc

I can't get the following code work on OSX

```
QString selectedFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open");

if(selectedFile == NULL) {
    return;
}

QString selectedPath = QDir::toNativeSeparators(selectedFile);

media = libvlc_media_new_path(vlc, selectedPath.toStdString().c_str());
libvlc_media_player_set_media(player, media);

libvlc_media_player_play(player);
```

It gives me the error

```
[00007ffd22c54758] core input error: open of `file:///path/to/file.avi' failed
[00007ffd22c54758] core input error: Your input can't be opened
[00007ffd22c54758] core input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///path/to/file.avi'. Check the log for details.
```

The same location works fine with VLC and other programs.

Comment: There should be 3 slashes, VLC also opens file:/// but not file://

Answer (score 1):

libvlc_media_new_path takes a local filename, not a URL. The Doxygen for LibVLC states "local filesystem path" for the parameter.

You have passed a file URL. So drop the "file://" prefix from your string.

You could try libvlc_media_new_location since that function uses URLs, but I don't know if it works for "file://" URLs.

Comment: selectedFile and selectedPath are only '/path/to/file.avi', I think libvlc adds the file:// prefix. Also tried manually adding both file:// and file:/// and using _location, but the result is the same

Comment: Hmm... I use this function all the time with local files without problems. I can't think what else. Have you tried getting a full log with -vvv.

Comment: Thanks, I realised that I had to put the lib files into MacOS/lib/vlc/lib instead of MacOS/lib. But now I have another problem, it chrashes when I play the video. Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/p2BfZDh5

Comment: You should post that as a separate question really.

Comment: If you are on Mac OS X you could try use libvlc from this archive: https://github.com/RSATom/WebChimera.js/releases/download/v.0.1.3/libvlc_2.2.1_mac.zip It contains the same files as in original VLC dmg but little bit rearranged to be workable outside VLC.app